# jQuery addEventListener

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener, polymer

In the [tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html), the author's use vanilla JavaScript:

```
var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');
   tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
}
```

I love jQuery so much that I want to marry it.

Q: How can I change the above code to use jQuery?
I tried to do this:

```
$(document).on('core-select','paper-tabs',function(e) {}
```

But the events passed in don't seem to be the same.
I gotta have more jQuery!

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$("paper-tabs").on("core-select", function() {`

Comment: Not if "paper-tabs" was dynamically added after DOM was loaded.

Comment: JQuery won't see `paper-tabs` elements that are encapsulated into ShadowDOM. This is a new concept to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**

```
$('selector').event(function(event){
     console.log(event);
     // output the event to see what is available to you
});
```

So for example...

```
    $('paper-tabs').click(function(event){
        alert('I was clicked!');
        // Do whatever else...
    });
```

Comment: Actually paper-tabs is a new tag by Polymer.

Comment: if 'paper-tags' is the actual tag, then you should be able to hook into it with just that selector. Unless there are a lot of 'paper-tag' elements. In which case, you might (or not) need another unique hook. Try logging the event & see if the info you need is available.